# Start wallaby.js automatically after visual studio solution got loaded

Tags: visual-studio, wallaby.js

I can not find a way to start wallaby.js automatically after a solution got loaded.

Beside the fact that one always (or mostly) wants to start wallaby.js anyway and thus starting it manually is just annoying it is also 'dangerous' if one forgets to activate it for a longer time as errors might enter the code. ;)

How can I ensure that wallaby.js is always running?
Thank you.

**Update 1**

After trying the solution from Artem, I created a shortcut for my solution file with the following target (and Start In empty):

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" devenv "%CD%\yourName.sln" /command Wallaby.StartRunner
```

As I did not want to use an absolute path, it is a little bit verbose but it is working great. If anyone can provide a simpler shortcut please feel free to edit this text.

**Update 2**

I just wanted to use the shortcut mentioned above inside a new Visual Studio 2017 solution and it was not working. wallaby.js just didn't start. The reason for that in my case was that my project using wallaby.js was inside a **solution folder** - *thus not at the root of the solution*. After moving it to the root level, everything was working again as expected.

Comment: Try this solution https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/340

Comment: Artem, I want to give you some points. Don't you want to paste your answer as an answer? ;) But thanks - I'll try it with devenv "your\solution\file\path.sln" /command Wallaby.StartRunner

Comment: @ArtemGovorov Is there anything one can do about the issue mentioned in "Update 2" above? It would be great, if solution folders would be possible!